# How can I use streams in java to aggregate vector A as in the excercise given below?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, arraylist, stream

I have been given this excercise: The vector A = [1,2,5,2,4,2,1,3,6,1,4] is given. Write the function that displays in a vector b all the unique elements and in another vector C all the values that have been repeated without repetition.

I have used ArrayList to work with and I cant figure out how to solve this excercise :(.
*Please help!*

> code so far:

```
 ArrayList<Integer> A=new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,5,2,4,2,1,3,6,1,4));
    List<Integer> B1=A.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Do you have to use a stream pipeline for this assignment? Here's a hint: you can use a map that keeps track of the count of each element. The keys will essentially be your vector B. Vector C will be the keys from the map where the value/count is greater than 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't use Stream for this. For best performance, I'd use two Sets.

```java
List<Integer> a = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,5,2,4,2,1,3,6,1,4));

Set<Integer> b = new LinkedHashSet<>();
Set<Integer> c = new LinkedHashSet<>();
for (Integer i : a)
    if (! b.add(i))
        c.add(i);

System.out.println(b);
System.out.println(c);
```

*Output*

```
[1, 2, 5, 4, 3, 6]
[2, 1, 4]
```

Of course, if you must use Stream API, then this might do.

```java
Map<Integer, Long> map = a.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Function.identity(), LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.counting()));
List<Integer> b = new ArrayList<>(map.keySet());
List<Integer> c = map.entrySet().stream().filter(e -> e.getValue() > 1)
        .map(Entry::getKey).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

*Output*

```
[1, 2, 5, 4, 3, 6]
[1, 2, 4]
```

The order of `b` is the same for both, i.e. the order of the first occurrence of a value.

The order of `c` differs, since the first solution has the order of occurrence of the first *repeat*, while the second solution has the same order as `b`, i.e. the order of the first *occurrence* of a value.

---

**UPDATE**

From [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68109689/how-can-i-use-streams-in-java-to-aggregate-vector-a-as-in-the-excercise-given-be/68110112?noredirect=1#comment120437872_68110112):

> The unique Array should be `[5,3,6]`, and the duplicate Array `[1,2,4]`

To get that result, add the following statement to the first version:

```java
b.removeAll(c);
```

*Output*

```
[5, 3, 6]
[2, 1, 4]
```

Change the code for building `b` in the second version to:

```java
List<Integer> b = map.entrySet().stream().filter(e -> e.getValue() == 1)
        .map(Entry::getKey).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

*Output*

```
[5, 3, 6]
[1, 2, 4]
```

Comment: This answer is not correct: The unique Array should be: [5,3,6] and the dublicate Array: [1,2,4]

Comment: @ZojeGabili Then please edit the question and say that, i.e. clarify the question, because that's obviously not how I read it, and it sure isn't what your code seems to attempt, using that `distinct()` call, which results in the same B list as this answer. I read the question as your attempt was good for B, but you needed help to figure out C.